# PHP-EWS: Cannot fetch room calendar

Tags: php, api, exchangewebservices

I'm having issues figuring out how to fetch the calendar of a resource (room) via the EWS Api. As a PHP Wrapper/Library I'm using the following: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices('server', 'user', 'pw');
$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;
$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;
$request->CalendarView = new EWSType_CalendarViewType();
$request->CalendarView->StartDate = '2014-02-05T15:18:34+03:00'; 
$request->CalendarView->EndDate = '2014-06-12T15:18:34+03:00'; 
$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::CALENDAR;
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox->EmailAddress = "roomname@adress.xxx";
$response = $ews->FindItem($request);
```

I tried to add the Mailbox->EmailAddress to the request, but I get the following error:

> [MessageText] => The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.
>                       [ResponseCode] => ErrorNonExistentMailbox

I guess the issue here is, that the room does not have an concrete mailbox associated with itself, so it cannot find it. Is there some kind of work around for this?
Can I access the folder directly? But how do I find the ID of that rooms calendar?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like EWSEditor to view the room resource?  I can connect to EWS and under Other use the Find Appointments and enter the mailbox and pull the appointments.  This way if you can connect and get the appointments you can view the appointments and see folder ids and most other information you might need.  It can give clues as to if everything is correctly setup.  It makes programming easier after examining.  I have stayed away from the PHP version because as I understand it might have issues getting the room resource.  I would be able to help more but I went with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this room resource newly created?  When you define a new room in Exchange it does not immediately create all the objects associated with it.  In my experience it has to be "visited" first, e.g. via OWA.  After that, there should be an actual mailbox associated with the SMTP.  So try to look at this room in Outlook or OWA and then see if you still get that error.

Comment: Well the room already has appointments assigned to it, so is that what you mean by "visiting" it? Or do you mean like actually impersonating the room?

Comment: Yea, if it has appts, then it's really there.

Comment: But why can't I get the folders for it then?

Comment: The only other possibility that occurs to me is some kind of permissions problem, altho when that happens, I usually get ErrorFolderNotFound.  Be sure also that userid you are using for the calendar access also has a real mailbox--I've seen cases where that causes all kinds of weird errors.  Be sure that user has full access permissions to the room MB.  You might also investigate impersonation.

Comment: Actually was an permissions issue. The IT-Dept. messed up the correct configuration. Thanks!

Comment: @xXx What exactly was it the IT dept fixed? Would be helpful for me.

Comment: @Alex I don't recall the exact thing cause I never worked with the AD but the permissions for accessing were not correctly configured